# Skip nested npm dependency from beeing installed

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, npm-install

When working on the AWS Lambda functions, in my `package.json` I have set `aws-sdk` package in `devDependencies` section because it's provided in AWS Lambda infrastructure, so it's not delivered with the deployment package.

However, when I've installed another production dependency, like `dynamoose`, it has `aws-sdk` set as a production dependency as well, so bundler is triggering `npm install` and attaching `aws-sdk` anyway.

Is there any possibility to configure `npm install` to avoid installing specific package no matter what?